# std::map with predicate vs. initialization list

Tags: c++, stl

I have an `std::map<string, string>` with a custom predicate:

```
struct PredIgnoreCase {
  bool operator()(const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2) const {
    std::string str1NoCase(str1), str2NoCase(str2);
    std::transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1NoCase.begin(), tolower);
    std::transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2NoCase.begin(), tolower);

    return (str1NoCase < str2NoCase);
  }
};
```

Now given

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> DIRECTORY_WITHCASE;
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string, PredIgnoreCase> DIRECTORY_NOCASE;
```

I initialize

```
 // Case-sensitive directory: case of string-key plays no role
  DIRECTORY_WITHCASE dirCaseSensitive{
      make_pair("John", "2345764"),
      make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
      make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
      make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
  };
```

And then when I initialize

```
  DIRECTORY_NOCASE dirCaseInsensitive(dirCaseSensitive.begin(),
                                      dirCaseSensitive.end());
```

`dirCaseInsensitive` prints

```
Jack - >32435348
JOHN - >2345765 <---- John in upper case
Sara - >42367236
```

However, if I initialize the `dirCaseInsensitive` like:

```
DIRECTORY_NOCASE dirCaseInSensitive{
      make_pair("John", "2345764"),
      make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
      make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
      make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
  };
```

It outputs correct map:

```
Jack - >32435348
John - >2345764 <----- John in lower case
Sara - >42367236
```

Why would different constructors of the same map, give different results?

Comment: *"John in lower case"* it is Capitalized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the order of pairs in each case is different. In the first case the constructor of `dirCaseInsensitive` is called (in effect) with the pairs in this order.

```
  make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
  make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
  make_pair("John", "2345764"),
  make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
```

This is the order of the pairs in `dirCaseSensitive` (assuming ASCII or similar character set).

In the second case the constructor of `dirCaseInsensitive` is called with pairs in the order given by the initialiser list.

```
  make_pair("John", "2345764"),
  make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
  make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
  make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
```

So you can see in the first case "JOHN" is before "John" so "JOHN" gets inserted but in the second case it's the other way around.

Comment: It's not accurate that the constructor is called with the pairs in a different order. That's the order the map *puts them in* as the final result of construction.

Comment: @aschepler Well in the first case the constructor is called with two iterators, and those iterators produce pairs in the order I indicated. I don't think I'm being inaccurate.

Comment: Oh, I see. You meant the constructor of `dirCaseInsensitive`, not `dirCaseSensitive`, but that's not clear.

Comment: @aschepler I've tried to clarify, although it's a bit wordy now.

Comment: I'm not sure that in the first case the constructor is called (in effect) with the pairs in this order, for if I run `for (auto it = dirCaseSensitive.begin(); it!=dirCaseSensitive.end(); ++it)
  cout << it->first <<" -> " << it ->second << endl;` I get the sequence  JOHN, Jack, John, Sara.

Answer (score 4):

The ordering matters here. If you switch `make_pair("JOHN", "2345765")` with `make_pair("John", "2345764")` in your `dirCaseInSensitive` construction, you will see the first output.

The case here is that when you first create:

```
DIRECTORY_WITHCASE dirCaseSensitive{
      make_pair("John", "2345764"),
      make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
      make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
      make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
};
```

due to ordering of the keys, your `"JOHN"` key is placed *as the first key* (before the `"John"` key). Now, if you try to use *that very map* to initialize the second one, it will first insert the `("JOHN", "2345765")` pair and then see the `("John", "2345764")` pair. It will case-insensitive compare the keys and figure out they are *equivalent*, so it won't insert the lowercase `"John"` pair.

So, to summarize, it's not really the usage of constructors. It's the surprising mix of your order of provided pairs and the ordering of they key, which do not match.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate only defines how the elements are ordered but it does not modify the elements. That you get once `JOHN` and once `John` is just by chance. In your first map `JOHN` comes first so when you use

```
DIRECTORY_NOCASE dirCaseInsensitive(dirCaseSensitive.begin(),
                                    dirCaseSensitive.end());
```

Then `JOHN` will be inserted first and then `John` is considered as equivalent by your predicate.

If you initialize it like this:

```
DIRECTORY_NOCASE dirCaseInSensitive{
     make_pair("John", "2345764"),
     make_pair("JOHN", "2345765"),
     make_pair("Sara", "42367236"),
     make_pair("Jack", "32435348"),
};
```

Then `John` is inserted first and because `JOHN` is considered the same key its not in the map.

The predicate does not modify the elements (they are passed as `const&`) but it just controls what elements come first and which ones are considered equivalent. If you expected to be all names in small letters because of the predicate, this is wrong. If you insert only capital letter names the map will contain only capital letter names.

To illustrate what is happening here, consider a map that ignores the least significant digit when comparing numbers as keys. After this:

```
rounded_map[1] = "one";
rounded_map[4] = "four";
rounded_map[11] = "eleven";
```

Then the map will contain values "one" and "eleven", but if you swap the order

```
rounded_map[4] = "four";
rounded_map[1] = "one";
rounded_map[11] = "eleven";
```

you'd get "four" and "eleven".